# On how to solve the ODE $v'-\frac{1}{v}=x$...

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I've been having trouble finding the general solution of $v$ for $v'-\frac{1}{v}=x$. I've attempted various substitutions in attempts of obtaining separation of variables or recognizable form to apply the method of the integrating factor. A couple of substitutions I've attempted:
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{v}$$
$$\beta=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$$
I tried others but threw out the scratch paper (yeah...would've helped now to see the other substitutions that didn't work so I don't reattempt them...). Does anyone have an idea of how to get this DE into a form we can play with? Please don't supply the final to the DE. I'm simply looking for direction down the proper path.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the ODE to solve ? If it is, it looks like a monster (at least to me).

Comment: What you probably want is: Abel differential equation of the second kind, with g(x) = 1, and f(x) = x. http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0125.pdf

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Anyway, this still be a very lucky case of Abel equation of the second kind.

Comment: Sorry for such a late response. That was indeed the ODE and the Airy equation was indeed the method to solve it... -_-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making the change of independent function $v=f+\frac{x^2}{2}$, we get
$$f'_x=\frac{1}{f+\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
Next interpret this as an equation for $x$ as a function of $f$:
$$x'_f=\frac{x^2}{2}+f.$$
This is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) solvable in terms of Airy functions: indeed, setting $x(f)=-2y'/y$, we get [Airy equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html) $2y''+f y=0$ for $y$.

Comment: Thank you!!! This helped out tremendously. I apologize for taking so long to thank you and mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

A change of function leads to an Riccati ODE. The usual method of solving leads to an ODE of Bessel kind. Finally the general solution is expressed on parametric form :

[image]

While I was typing my answer, "Start wearing purple" posted his answer which is based on the same method.