# Closed form solution to an ordinary differential equaiton

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form, fundamental-solution

How to solve the following ordinary differential equation?

$$y'(x)=
\frac{C_1}{y(x)}
+C_2 C_3 \cos\left(C_3 x\right) +C_4$$

where $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4\in \mathbb{R}$ are all constants.

It looks simple but difficult to solve.

Comment: To me, it does not look simple at all !

Comment: A much simpler similarly looking equation was found to have a rather nontrivial solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1674154/73025). However it does not seem that in your case we can get to Riccati. So I tend to declare your equation unsolvable, at least for generic values of constants.

Comment: I would suggest solve it numerically.